# is it more optimal to assign and then multiply with *= ? in this case?

Tags: performance, optimization

In the interest of being as light weight as possible in code that must run potentially 60 times per second or more in an animation scenario, I became curious over a seemingly insignificant 2 lines of code.

I know that the performance benefit is probably nil, but in the interest of understanding better how my code actually works in the CPU, I would like to ask the following question:

Does one of these sequences generate a more optimal (even minimally) set of cpu operations, and why? (or possibly, "why not?")

assume an un-optimized compilation scenario, obviously.

```
objA.scaleX = _inversionFactor * value;
objA.scaleY = value;
```

vs.

```
objA.scaleX = objA.scaleY = value;
objA.scaleX *= _inversionFactor;
```

Comment: If you have two horses and want to know which one is faster, [Race Your Horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Comment: indeed, i could benchmark them.  but I would like to know from the compiler/performance people on these channels, how the cpu actually sees these operations.  I know it's a little out of my depth, but I'm so curious, because my gut says that the 2nd way will generate faster code...  but i want to know WHY! :)

Comment: @DavidColeman: you could always just view the actual instructions the compiler generates and then you would see exactly what the CPU uses. One feature most debuggers offer is to let you look at, and step through, the individual compiled instructions.

Comment: yes i could, but i'm hoping that someone can explain to me what it is that I would be seeing.  I'm talking from a purely theoretical point here, because in my case, i'm dealing with flash and js, in both cases there are SOOO many levels of interpretation involved that getting the assembly instructions is simply not part of the picture.  my question has to do with code THEORY, in that "in a perfect world where this is expressed as pure cpu instructions or assembly, is one of these better"

Comment: the second version assign X once then read it back, multiply and assign back again, so theoretically it'll be slower. But with optimized compiler things might not be like that

Comment: This question does not comply to the rules for [tag:compiler-construction]. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: I didn't think it was indiscriminate.  I'm curious if something compiles to more efficient instructions.  asking on a compilers channel seemed obvious to me.  Sorry.

Comment: interesting @LưuVĩnhPhúc, i had imagined it that the 2nd one would be
    pop a value to a register
    push it to x
    push it to y
    calculate x*_factor
    push it to x

where as the first one would actually do more work by reading, calculating, storing assigning and then reading again for the same value to assign it a 2nd time...

hence, I'm asking people who hopefully understand this better than I.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> assume an un-optimized compilation scenario, obviously.

Since you are interested in [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) and [optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization), it is not obvious, but rather schizophrenic to assume that.

> I would like to know from the compiler/performance people on these
>   channels, how the cpu actually sees these operations.

The CPU does not see these operations at all, it sees what the compiler has made of them, and that depends on the compiler, obviously.

> "in a perfect world where this is expressed as pure cpu instructions
>   or assembly, is one of these better"

You are overlooking that there is not only one way to express your source code as CPU instructions, and thus your question is underspecified.